# Select Distinct records by IDictionary<string,object> property in an object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of the following:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Qty { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string, object> Dxo { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to merge records that have the same dictionary value (all the props in the dictionary are the same) and sum the quantities of the merged records.

I have the following query:

```
var result = from f in foos.Select(x => x.Exo).Distinct()
             join p2 in foos on exo equals p2.Exo into gr
             select new
             {
                 Qty = gr.Select(x => x.Qty).Sum(),
                 Exo = exo
             };
```

The distinct part of my query does not seem to be working. My result has the same number of records.

Perhaps it not possible to compare IDictionary in this manner. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do not have any method that compares a dictionary against another dictionary and there isn't a standard compare method in the dictionary class.

Comment: `on exo equals p2.exo` ← That won't work. Joins can compare primitive types (like string, int, etc) or they can use anonymous types where the properties are primitive types with the same property names (example `on new {Name = "dave"} equals new {Name = o.name}`. Dictionary is a complex type so if you wanted to do a join on the dictionary you would need to write some comparison operator or implement an interface that could do this but I do not think you could do this in a join.

Comment: I would recommend you write out what you are trying to do using some `foreach` loops and get that to actually work (not pseudo code). Then you would have a better chance at being able to convert that to linq. You could create a full [mcve] and add it to your question doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need (and what is not available out of the box) is ability to check for equality for instances of `IDictionary<string, object>`.

When you use `.Distinct()`, such instances will be compared using standard `.Equals()` implementation, which is just compare by reference - not what you need.

Also, as you need to process "equal" records after that, it's better to use `.GroupBy()` rather than `.Distinct()` with `Join`, as that is more obvious and more performant (as much as we can talk about performance in this task anyway).

So, assuming we have some `FooComparer` which can compare items, your query should look like:

```
var result = foos
    .GroupBy(x => x.Dxo, x => x, new FooComparer())
    .Select(x => new Foo
    {
        Qty = x.Sum(y => y.Qty),
        Dxo = x.First().Dxo,
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Now switching to that comparer.

I read this statement from you question "all the props in the dictionary are the same" as "every dictionary has exactly the same set of keys, and all dictionaries are not null". That is pretty strict statement which simplifies our task, so comparer can look like:

```
public class FooComparer : IEqualityComparer<IDictionary<string, object>>
{
    public bool Equals(IDictionary<string, object> x, IDictionary<string, object> y)
    {
        return x.Keys.All(k => x[k] == y[k]);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IDictionary<string, object> obj)
    {
        return obj.Aggregate(0, (hash, x) => (x.Value?.GetHashCode() ?? 0) ^ hash);
    }
}
```

Several notices here:

- if values in dictionary are pretty complex objects (i.e. non primitive ones like int / string), then `x[k] == y[k]` from above needs further coding to compare them,
- calculating hashcode here is just a fake (but which should just work); I would never use that for production code

Speaking of which - I would never use LINQ-based approach for such task. I suspect complexity of .Net `Distinct` / `Group By` is around O(n^2) for LINQ-to-objects (I haven't look for internal implementation, but I highly suspect no real optimizations can be done there for generic approach).

So having enumeration of every dictionary with subsequent comparisons of every item in it for every damn `GetEquals` in comparer during GroupBy is a big red NO WAY.

I would rework that in foreach loop, with maybe some caching for hash / equals, or maybe changed whole approach to solve that task in a different way from start so that you'll accumulate results in the same object from start.

Comment: Thank you so much for the very detailed response. I will put this into production.

As a side note, since I am trying find like IDictionary objects (and was in a rush), I simply "flattened" the whole object to a json string and then compared strings. Did the job for now. 

Again thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can [pass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Distinct__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__) custom [IEqualityComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8):

```
from f in foos.Distinct(new FooEqualityComparer())
```

which would look like this:

```
class FooEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals(Foo one, Foo two)
    {
        // your implementation goes here
        // where you for instance compare Exo
    }

    public int GetHashCode (Foo foo)
    {
        // your implementation goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I do appreciate it. All answers pretty much suggested the same approach, but I awarded it to @Lanorkin because of the level of detail in his response.

Comment: @JulianDormon: He posted his answer later than me so I haven't seen it. Fair enough, he well deserves the acceptance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method `IsSameAs` on the IDictionary. That method should return a boolean value indicating if 2 dictionaries are equal or not. Then you can use the LINQ like

```
foos.Where(f1 => foos.Any(f2 => f1.exo.IsSameAs(f2.exo))).Select(....)
```

Of course, one drawback is that it will match with self along with others.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I do appreciate it. All answers pretty much suggested the same approach, but I awarded it to @Lanorkin because of the level of detail in his response.